# Is it possible to QUERY where a range in a row is not null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to QUERY a Google Sheet where a range of cells in a row are not null. This is an example of my data:

[image: Example Data]

I am tyring to get my formula to show the rows that have anything populated in columns E, F, G or H so using the example data above, I want the QUERY to return this:

[image: Query]

The following formula returns only the Headers because it's looking to see if each cell is not null.

```
=Query(A1:H6,"Select * where E is not null and F is not null and G is not null and H is not null",1)
```

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let use `or` instead `and`

```
=Query(A1:H6,"Select * where E is not null or F is not null or G is not null or H is not null",1)
```

Comment: That worked thank you. I did originally try that but I had another where statement in my Query which I put 'or' after and now realised I should have put 'and' before all of the 'or is not null' statements.

Comment: you can add `()` like `where ... and (... or ... or ...)` to separate the conditions